# Injectivity and the lower bound of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Could you please explain why the operator $T:X \to Y$ (from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$) is injective if there is a constant $c>0$ such that for all $x \in X$:
$$
c \|x\| \leq \|Tx\|
$$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Tx=0$, then $\|Tx\|=0$, so $c\|x\|\leq 0$, so $\|x\|\leq 0$ since $c>0$, so $\|x\|=0$, and hence $x=0$, so $\ker T=\{0\}$.

Comment: So $Tx=0 \implies x=0 \implies \exists T^{-1} \implies T \; \text{is injective}$. Thank you very much for the great reply!